# What new NPCs are available in 1.2?

Tags: terraria

I seem to recall it being stated that the 1.2 update includes a number of new, friendly NPCs. What are they, and what are the requirements for each to appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC) and [this wiki](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/NPC):

[Dye Trader](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye_Trader) will move in when:

- Any material used to make dye is in the player's inventory, such as the yellow marigold.

[Party Girl](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Party_Girl) will move in when:

- You have at least 8 NPCs (Note: There is a 2% chance for the Party girl to spawn each morning, so it can take a while for her to arrive.)

[Steampunker](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Steampunker) will move in when:

- The player has killed any Hard Mode boss and there is a suitable house for her.

[Painter](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Painter) will move in when:

- The player has obtained at least 4 NPCs.

[Witch Doctor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Witch_Doctor) will move in when:

- The player kills The Queen Bee.

[Pirate](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pirate) will move in when:

- The player fights the pirates by using a treasure map obtained by killing hard-mode sea monsters.

[Cyborg](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cyborg) will move in when:

- The player kills Plantera.

[Truffle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Truffle) will move in when:

- The player has a house with Mushroom Furniture (Mushroom Workbench/Mushroom Doors/Mushroom Chair) in a surface Mushroom Biome.

**Note**: Just like with any NPC, the player must have an [empty and valid house](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Home) available.

Comment: I'm gonna assume 'you like to party' has something to do with multiplayer. Or explosives.

Comment: Also: Pirate, Witch Doctor, Cyborg, and Truffle.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Wow, there are a lot.  Is there any info on them yet?

Comment: I thought the painter just required that you find a painting?

Comment: @Reafexus: I'm not sure about that.  Shortly after I loaded the game following the update, the Painter moved into my house.

Comment: Do they ever move out?  For example, if you no longer have the proper materials in your inventory will the dye trader leave?

Comment: @Batophobia: I don't think so.  No other past NPC has has such a restriction, either.  Of course, any NPC will move out if his/her house no longer qualifies as a house.

Comment: According to the wiki, "You like to party" means "You need at least 8 NPC's".

Comment: Not only will they not move out, they will actually return if they should ever die!  At least...that is what happened in previous versions.

Answer (score -1):

New NPC'so in 1.2

1. Wall of Flesherer
2. Night Owl
3. Capricorn Geni
4. Sawdan

Comment: These are inaccurate. Are you sure you have the right game?