# How do you get the party girl?

Tags: terraria

Can you please tell me how to get the party girl and what she sells for how much?

Comment: you are probably recieving negative votes as you showed no attempt to prior research (a simple google search got the answer).

Comment: How to spawn each NPC: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132930/30210

Answer (score 9):

[Party Girl](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Party_Girl) information.. the following pre-reqs must be met before she moves in like a normal NPC

- There is no NPC waiting to move in.
- There is an empty house.
- You have at least 8 other NPCs. (May not be a necessary prerequisite since Party Girl can spawn with less than 8 other NPCs in a world. Could possibly affect spawn chance though.)

Answer (score 6):

The party girl has a 2% chance to spawn/move in each day when the following requirements are met:

1. Have at least 8 NPCs
2. No one is waiting to move in
3. You have an empty room for her to move in to.

She sells fun party/cosmetic items like the bubble machine, confetti gun, fireworks and bubble wand.

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Party_Girl